# Logism LED matrix (sprinkler system)

Tags: led, led-matrix

[image][image]

In my digital circuits class I have a project as shown in the picture. I am having trouble because I cannot get the led's to light up in sequence(left to right) I don't know why the lines are red. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red means there's multiple drivers for the net with different values.

I can't quite tell from your picture, but it looks almost like all of the vertical decoder lines are connected to the horizontal wire at the bottom. That would cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: That worked! But I still can't get the LED's to simulate. Only one will light up.

Comment: @Austin Collier Which LED is lighting up?